# Ubuntu 22.04 wired connection keep disconnecting

Tags: ethernet

My ubuntu's Ethernet connection is disconnecting every 15 minutes and it again starts connecting when i restart.
It's so irritating to restart every 15 mins.
Is there any fix for this.
Btw I'm using Ubuntu 22.04lts

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately, there's not enough actionable information here. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the Terminal output of `sudo lspci` and `sudo lshw -c network` (2) the brand and model of your computer (3) any relevant details from `/var/log/syslog` around the time that your network connection stops. With this, it *may* be possible to identify a problem and offer a solution 

Comment: And explain, what you mean by "disconnect". "link down" or how do you detect it? And what is between your computer and the "internet"?

Comment: I do have a similar problem. Can you disconnect your cable and connect it again to check if the network manager works? It does for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `sudo lshw -C network | grep logical` to display the wired connection's logical name. Then, something like:
`sudo ip link set [logical name of wired connection: enxxxxxxxxx] up sudo dhclient enxxxxxxxxx`

I am not sure why 22.04 no longer reads /etc/network/interfaces where you can add in something like:
`auto enxxxxxxxxx iface enxxxxxxxxx inet dhcp`

It seemed to detect the wired connection in the docked state, but after auto-switching a few times to undocked (e.g., wireless only) my laptop decided to drop the wired connection icon in the taskbar, and "Network Settings" only shows VPN??